# Possible to Split and Export a Table in Batches Using Where Clause to Split

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that looks like this.

```
ID  Project Type    Time
1   A       Start    1:00
1   A       End      1:10
1   B       Start    2:00
2   B       End      2:10
2   B       Start    2:30
2   B       End      2:45
3   C       End      3:00
3   D       Start    3:10
4   D       End      3:20
4   E       Start    1200
```

I am wondering how to export this into 4 separate flat files (CSV or TXT), by using a Where Clause on the ID filed.  I thought of looping through all records in the table and filtering by ID.  I hacked together some SQL, below, but this is missing something.

```
DECLARE @CursorTestID INT = 1;
DECLARE @RunningTotal BIGINT = 0;
DECLARE @RowCnt BIGINT = 0;

-- get a count of total rows to process 
SELECT @RowCnt = COUNT(0) FROM dbo.mytable1;
--print(@RowCnt) 

WHILE @CursorTestID <= @RowCnt
BEGIN

   select * from mytable1 
       where ID = (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM mytable1) as table
   SET @CursorTestID = @CursorTestID + 1 

END
```

I want to end up with 4 flat files, based on the 4 distinct IDs.  It doesn't have to be elegant or fast either.  I'm just wondering if this concept will work.  I don't have access to SSIS.

Thanks to all who look at this.

Answer (score 0):

You might try the MOD operator (%) which gives you the integer remainder of division.  So then `WHERE id % 4 = 0` would be your 1st pass, `WHERE id % 4 = 1` would be your 2nd pass, etc.  Should result in a 'fairly' even distribution.